# Parse.com query to retrieve relational field

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I have a table on [parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html) called `user` and it has a field called `amici` that is a relational field that points to the same table `user`. I have made a function to retrieve a field `amici` by a `user` but the data returned is very strange. Can anyone suggest me a function(in rest) to retrieve field amici and return data as:

```
[{
    "amici": {},
    "createdAt": "2013-07-27T13:46:25.519Z",
    "email": "cc@libero.it",
    "image": {},
    "objectId": "gEyO9j55Th",
    "updatedAt": "2013-08-01T13:37:22.144Z",
    "username": "cc"
}, {
    //... 2
}, {
    //... 3
}, {
    //... 4
}, {
    //... 5
}];
```

**Equivalent Browser Console Output**

```
Object {results: Array[5]}
results: Array[5]
0: Object
amici: Object
createdAt: "2013-07-27T13:46:25.519Z"
email: "cc@libero.it"
image: Object
objectId: "gEyO9j55Th"
updatedAt: "2013-08-01T13:37:22.144Z"
username: "cc"
__proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
```

Comment: On further reading, I think you are referring to https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html in your question! This answer won't be applicable in that aspect. Instead please add more code that you have written and also the weird output that you are getting.

Comment: i need to understant how make a rest call to get all the content of field amici in a given user

Comment: I get that, but to help you, people will need to look at more code that you have already written! So, for instance, begin by providing the code that defines the structure of your actual users table. Then provide the code that you tried and which gave you the unexpected output, and so on! Remember that people are contributing their time here and the more relevant code and test cases you give, the faster it is for someone random to setup a test bench and help you! :)

Comment: just as an example, I wrote you a decent sized answer, and then deleted it when I realised that your question was about consuming the parse.com api...

Answer (score 0):

1. You really need to show the code you are using to call the api otherwise we can't tell you definitively what you are doing wrong.

But I'm willing to take a stab that you aren't fetching the amici object.

You should "include" the "amici" field and the parse.com will handle fetching all the fields in "amici"